# How do I make social media buttons stay in a fixed position on the screen while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, social-networking

In asp.net, how do I create a way to contain social media buttons and keep them in the same place while I scroll throughtout the page? Simply using "position:fixed" is not working.

css page:

```
.sharebox
{
    position: fixed; 
    top: 70px;
    width: 50px;
    height:110px;
    left: 30px; 
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #335500;
}
```

Then my social media buttons are inside a div class="sharebox"

Comment: Browser[s] this is not working in? Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/jYq8f/

Comment: I've only tested it in internet explorer

Comment: Version 6,7,8,9,10? make sure your browser does not have a bad version of the file in the cache. Clear it.

Comment: Do you try to get `position: fixed` work in IE6?